# Trigger behavior as soon as a bound input text changes

Tags: angular

Maintaining some old code.  One page has a form with user input like this:

```html
<input type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="newAcct.firstName" (change)="validate()"/>
<input type="text" name="lastName"  [(ngModel)]="newAcct.lastName"  (change)="validate()"/>
```

At present, `validate()` will only run once the user has clicked or tabbed out of the input box.  I would like it to run after every change to the inputs - for example, if newAcct.lastName had the value "D" and the user hit the backspace key to make the value an empty string, I want it to immediately run `validate()` because `validate()`'s behavior disables the Submit button and highlights the fact that the Last Name input box is empty.  At present, the Submit button will still appear valid until the user clicks on something else...such as the Submit button.

I've seen something about setting something up to run after every keypress or click, but I don't want it to run when someone hits Tab or an arrow key, just the moment the value changes.  There's also multiple of such forms on this page with multiple functions I'd like to trigger on specific value changes, which seems like it'd be a problem.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you try to use ngModelChange instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind to the `(input)` event, which fires every time the value changes by user input: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple input events?  The particular component I'm having issues with has multiple radically-different forms (using that term loosely) where I need different behavior for each form when their inputs change.